# Event processed confirmation in Kafka

Tags: java, asynchronous, stream, apache-kafka

I'm trying to achieve some kind of event processing in Kafka. I've got some producers which post events to Kafka queue. I've also consumers which get the event, process it, and save processed data in DB. However, I need to be sure that EVERY event had been processed and finished. What if something crash unexpectedly during processing of event after taking it from a queue? How can I inform Kafka that this particular event is still not processed? Are there any known patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka streams Version 0.10.* by design has "At least once" semantics. Once you are using DB if every event has its own key you will also get "Exactly once semantic " since there is no duplications if you write to the same key.

If you want to make sure that this is correct.
Start kafka,
Generate Data,
Start DB,
Start your stream,
Make sure data is getting there,
Now stop your DB,
Kill stream while it gets some errors,
Start DB again,
And you will see that Kafka reproduces the data into your DB again.

For further reading you can go [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/)